# How can I mark the question and answer I am interested in?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I wonder how I can mark the questions and answers(the whole page)which I am interested in and I might return to later future.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16296/how-can-i-mark-the-question-and-answer-i-am-interested-in-?/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

#### Follow questions

On the top right side of every question, you can see a "Follow" button. Click that to follow the question.

[image: image description]

When you ask a question, you automatically follow it.

#### Followed questions list

Then you can go to your profile and followed questions, and you'll see the list of all your followed questions.

[image: image description]

This is the direct link to your list:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/?sort=favorites

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1